# Pass arguments to base class

Tags: c#, inheritance, private

I'm currently working on a C# project, i'm new to C# so i'm not that familiar with classes and all. anyway here is my sample program structure:

```
 class foo 
 { 
     public foo(String txt) : base(new MyInnerClass()) { }
     private class MyInnerClass
     { }
 }
```

the problem is that i want to access my ***String txt*** to *MyInnerClass*, but i don't know how. The value of ***String txt*** comes from other class that will access this ***class foo***. Any idea how?

Comment: what class does `foo` derive from?

Answer (score 1):

You can either create a settable property on `MyInnerClass`, or give it a constructor that takes a string, as you've done with `foo`.

```
class foo 
{ 
   public foo(String txt) : base(new MyInnerClass(txt)) { }

   private class MyInnerClass
   { 
       private string text;
       public MyInnerClass(string txt)
       { 
           this.text = txt;
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just pass it into constructor of base.

```
class foo { 
public foo(String txt):
           base(new MyInnerClass(txt)){
             } 
   private class MyInnerClass { //some code lines } }
```